# Meaning of electron displaced to another quantum state in another location

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, solid-state-physics, wavefunction, electronic-band-theory

For example, in a p-n junction scenario where the electron is displaced from LOCATION A, due to diffusion to a lower quantum state at LOCATION B in the p-type silicon, as seen in the following diagram : [image]

does this mean that the electron that initially had a higher probability of being found at LOCATION A, now due to displacement due to diffusion has a higher probability of being found at the new location, location B ?

Is this the correct interpretation?

As the conventional quantum mechanical model of the near-free electron cloud, implies that the probability of finding the electron in a crystal is near uniform everywhere. So what does this mean to have the electron move from one location x to another , when the probability of finding a near free electron is already uniform.

Or that the probability initially peaks at LOCATION A, then after displacement the probability then peaks at LOCATION B

Comment: No, the interpretation of quantum mechanics and solid state physics given in the question is not correct.

Comment: The distances involved in $pn$ junctions are typically on the order of micrometers.